# error in passing the 2D array to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

unusual error in function solve when I pass the dp array to the function.

```
int n,k;
int solve(int n, int k, int dp[n+1][k+1]) 
{ 
  // some code
} 
int main(){
  int t; cin>>t;
  while(t--){
     cin>>n;
     cin>>k;
     int dp[n+1][k+1];
    memset(dp, -1,sizeof(dp));
    cout<<solve(n,k,dp)<<endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

why this 
error: use of parameter outside function body before '+' token
 int solve(int n, int k, int dp[n+1][k+1]) 
I am not able to understand why is this error

Comment: Because it's not valid C++.

Comment: Let me direct you to `std::vector`, which can be used in the manner the code is trying to use a C-style array.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023066/count-of-equal-adjacent-elements-in-2d-array/57025549#57025549) here will be helpful on learning how to properly pass an array to a function

Answer (score 2):

In C++ array sizes must be *compile time constants*.

This is not legal C++

```
int dp[n+1][k+1];
```

because `n` and `k` are variables not constants.

And this is not legal C++

```
int solve(int n, int k, int dp[n+1][k+1])
```

for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the array's size can't be changed dynamically. Granted you are reading in the sizes, this will cause issues. You can hard code the value of n,k for testing purposes

```
int dp[10][10];
int solve(int n, int k, int dp[10][10])
```

or attempt using a vector instead.